# Function works with lsqcurvefit but not nlinfit

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to get a nonlinear least squares fit for the following function:

```
Nloc = 250;

d = 1 / Nloc;

m = 0.5; %Initial guess

ncmfun = @(m, p) arrayfun(@(p) betainc(d, Nloc*m .* p, Nloc*m .* (1 - p), 'upper'), p);
```

Where m is the parameter being fit, Nloc and d are constants, and p and freq are vectors of positive real numbers and of the same length (I triple checked). When I use lsqcurvefit everything works fine:

```
[mfit,resnorm,]  = lsqcurvefit(ncmfun, m, p, freq, 0, 1)
```

Also, if I use any m to evaluate the function, everything works fine as well. However when I use nlinfit:

```
[mfit,R,Jac,CovB,MSE,ErrorModelInfo] = nlinfit(p, freq, ncmfun, m)
```

I get the following error(s):

```
Error using betainc

Z must be real and non-negative.

Error in @(p)betainc(d,Nloc*m.*p,Nloc*m.*(1-p),'upper')


Error in
@(m,p)arrayfun(@(p)betainc(d,Nloc*m.*p,Nloc*m.*(1-p),'upper'),p)


Error in nlinfit>@(b,x)w.*model(b,x) (line 206)
        modelw = @(b,x) w.*model(b,x);

Error in nlinfit>LMfit (line 486)
    yfit = model(beta,X);

Error in nlinfit (line 207)
        [beta,J,~,cause,fullr] = LMfit(X,yw,
        modelw,beta,options,verbose,maxiter);

Error in Sloan_NCM_Parameterize_Nm (line 37)
[mfit,R,Jac,CovB,MSE,ErrorModelInfo] = nlinfit(p, freq,
ncmfun, m);
```

What's especially frustrating was this same script was working a couple weeks ago. I then tried to use it again and it no longer works. I tried to go through and see if I accidentally changed something and didn't remember, but I can't find any errors. Furthermore, I'm confused as to why lsqcurvefit works but not nlinfit. I'd like to use nlinfit because it provides me with more statistical information about the error.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

They both use the same algorithm to identify a solution, however, you are explicitly stating an upper and lower bound for your solution in `lsqcurvefit` which ensures your incomplete beta function behaves. You don't have this option in `nlinfit`. I'm not sure what you did before (you can always look at the command history)

You have a few options from this point:

1 - programatically intercept every value that goes to ncmfun, by either expending your anonymous functions in what my nightmares are made of, or creating your own m-file for it. If the value is outside of [0,1] return progressively higher error value (with the boundaries being >>> then any possible value within the set)

2 - Try to force a quicker convergence by playing with some of the parameters (perhaps by using a robust fitting option (cf documentation))